# 'bequeathed me' -or- 'bequeathed to me'

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I'm unsure how to correctly construct the following sentence using the past tense of the word 'bequeath' and/or 'donate'.

> It's what I wanted to do since I was 14, the year my math teacher
> bequeathed to me a Model 1 Radio Shack TRS80.

> It's what I wanted to do since I was 14, the year my math teacher
> bequeathed me a Model 1 Radio Shack TRS80.

> It's what I wanted to do since I was 14, the year my math teacher
> donated me a Model 1 Radio Shack TRS80.

> It's what I wanted to do since I was 14, the year my math teacher
> donated to me a Model 1 Radio Shack TRS80.

I'm open to any reconstruction suggestion as well.

Answer (score 1):

First, there are two ways to order direct and indirect objects.

> She gave me milk
>
> She gave milk to me

are both grammatically valid forms.

Second, neither "bequeath" nor "donate" are idiomatic. The first, "bequeath," has a primary meaning of bestow by will after death. Are you saying that your teacher died and provided for you in a will? If not, the word conveys a meaning very different from what you mean.

The verb "donate" is not quite so bizarre, but still sounds odd. According to Webster, the primary meaning of "donate" is "to make a gift of [something], especially to a public or charitable cause." A single student is seldom if ever considered a public cause.

There is a perfectly good verb that does not create weird connotations that you probably do not intend, namely "give." It is true that "give" has a wide field of meaning so you may want to characterize it appropriately

> gave me a present of a ...
>
> gave me a prize of a ...
>
> gave me the unexpected gift of a ...

Comment: _Bequeath_ can be used in a semi-humorous way of someone leaving behind an item for someone else to use when they change jobs or move home.

Comment: @ Kate Bunting True enough, but I hesitate to refer to intentional distortions of primary meanings at a site for learners. It does not sound in this case as though the intended meaning is to joke about the gift.

Comment: Thanks Jeff ~ I appreciate your meticulous precision in highlighting the definition of both terms. That said - further context (not originally provided) might have revealed a more light-hearted tone as @KateBunting suggested. I still don't understand tho which form to use for either term - that is if I were to to use one or the other in a more appropo context. Thanks. I will probably go with what you've suggested.